# How to check if a file exists in Powershell?

Tags: powershell-3.0

I need to check if .jpg and .png files from the folder **$pathSource** exist also in the folder **$pathJPG**

Problem is it never enters in the if statement (although files do exist)

```
$pathSource="C:\Users\fransua\Desktop\nicolas.moussion@gmail.com\wetransfer-bd287a"
$pathJPG=$pathSource+"\JPG\"
$items = (Get-ChildItem -Force -Path $pathSource )
$i=0
foreach ($item in $items) {
    Write-Output "Fichier source : $($item)"
    $itemToCheck=$pathJPG+$item
    Write-Output "Fichier dest : $($itemToCheck)"
    if ((Test-Path $itemToCheck))  {
        Write-Output "Fichier copié dans jpg : $($itemToCheck) numéro $($i)"
        $i+=1
    }
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Here is the resulting string of the $itemToCheck : C:\Users\fransua\Desktop\nicolas.moussion@gmail.com\wetransfer-bd287a\JPG\Zoe Menard.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
try with "PathType Leaf" as shown below?

if ((Test-Path $itemToCheck -PathType Leaf))  {
    Write-Output "Fichier copié dans jpg : $($itemToCheck) numéro $($i)"
    $i+=1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved ! it was just a mispelling JPG instead of JPEG (sorry for that)